# MongoDB for big tile map game 1000x1000

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial, mongodb-geospatial

I started learning mongodb and was trying to figure out which way is better suited for a large 2d tile map if I need to store a large number of tiles.
In my case, the player has to fill in the free 4 tiles ([quad 2x2](https://i.ibb.co/3hg7z2z/2022-06-18-032824557.png)) - this is a kind of castle.

Let's assume that the database contains a document like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62ad13e2a4658cfa758956d4"
  },
  "data": {
    "player_id": "asdfadsf-asdfasdfas-fasdfsdaf-asdffds"
  },
  "location": [[
     [ 0, 0],
     [ 0, 1],
     [ 1, 1],
     [ 1, 0],
  ]]
}
```

Is it possible to make a geospatial query to find a free random 2x2 square for the next castle that never intersects with the first one?
Maybe the mongo geospatial query is not suitable for this case?